# HAProxy ACL - Backend resolution

Tags: haproxy

Given this HAProxy configuration:

```
    acl acl-api-qa hdr(host) -i qa.example.com
      use_backend backend-api-qa if acl-api-qa
    backend backend-api-qa
      mode http
      balance leastconn
      server-template api 10 _api._env=qa.service.consul resolvers consul resolve-prefer ipv4 check


    acl acl-api-test hdr(host) -i test.example.com
      use_backend backend-api-test if acl-api-test
    backend backend-api-test
      mode http
      balance leastconn
      server-template api 10 _api._env=test.service.consul resolvers consul resolve-prefer ipv4 check
```

Traffic is only getting routed to qa.example.com but test.example.com is a 503: service unavaliable as HAProxy seems to short-circuit when it encounters the first backend and ignores the next set of ACls and backends. Is this an ordering problem? can I not interweave ACLs and backends? Should these be built out as an ACLs section followed by a Backends section?

Answer (score 0):

that appears to be the case? This worked for me:

```
    acl acl-api-test hdr(host) -i test.example.com
    acl acl-api-qa hdr(host) -i qa.example.com


    use_backend backend-api-test if acl-api-test
    use_backend backend-api-qa if acl-api-qa


    backend backend-api-test
      mode http
      balance leastconn
      server-template api 10 _api._env=test.service.consul resolvers consul resolve-prefer ipv4 check

    backend backend-api-qa
      mode http
      balance leastconn
      server-template api 10 _api._env=qa.service.consul resolvers consul resolve-prefer ipv4 check
```

but results in a fair bit of duplicated code in my consul template. does HAProxy expect `acl`, `use-backend`, and `backend` to be grouped into distinct groups?